# Saber o total de valores no array php

Tags: php

Preciso resolver uma situação com o array, parece ser simples mas não estou conseguindo!

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
$total = array("6.00","7.00","9.5","10","5.5","7.75","6.5","9");
```

Preciso saber a quantidade de valores menores que 7.
Não quero saber quais são e sim a quantidade?
Por exemplo:
sei que tem o 6.00 o 5.5 e o 6.5.
Quero que retorne total: 3 valores.

Answer (score 2):

Mais um exemplo de como fazer utilizando [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) (como o próprio nome já deixa bem claro. Uma função para filtrar determinada informação no `array`) e [count](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) (utilizada para contar elementos), criei a função `addLessThanSeven(float $val)` que recebe um valor do tipo `float`, e por fim retorna os valores menores que 7 (não fiz nenhum tratamento de erro).

Exemplo:

```
<?php

    $total = array("6.00", "7.00", "9.5", "10", "5.5", "7.75", "6.5", "9");

    function addLessThanSeven(float $val)
    {
        return ($val < 7);
    }

    echo count(array_filter($total, "addLessThanSeven"));
    //3
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa usar aspas nos números. Se usar, eles serão tratados como string.

```
$total = array(6.00,7.00,9.5,10,5.5,7.75,6.5,9);

$contador = 0;

foreach ($total as $item) 
{
    if($item < 7)
    {
        $contador++;
    }
}

echo "Quantidade de números menores que 7: ".$contador;
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php), que vai reduzir esses `array` em um outro tipo de dado com um valor especifico, no caso a redução é a contagem de itens que são menores que 7, criando uma função `sum($a, $b)` onde o valor da variável `$a` é o inicial e o valor de `$b` e o valor de cada posição desse `array`, verificando com um ternário se esse valor é menor do que `7` e se for satisfeito retorna o valor 1 para acrescimo ou valor 0, exemplo:

```
<?php    

    $total = array("6.00","7.00","9.5","10","5.5","7.75","6.5","9");
    
    function sum($a, $b)
    {
        $a += (float)$b < 7 ? 1 : 0;
        return $a;
    }
    
    echo array_reduce($total, 'sum', 0);
```